# Is it possible to fork snap client to disable mandatory automatic updates?

Tags: snap

There has been a certain backlash against mandatory automatic updates in snapcraft. Since the client is open source, I am wondering, is there a possibility to modify that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are using an IoT system and that always updates itself.
The basic idea is ... if you don't like IoT don't use IoT. Snaps are not mandatory and other methods of installing will also be available.

Mind that your problem is solvable by blocking updates.

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d api.snapcraft.io -j DROP
```

will block updates (create some kind of daemon to keep this in active) and ...

```
sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -d api.snapcraft.io -j DROP
snap refresh
```

can be used to manually update so I do not really understand why you would need to fork snap.

Comment: Are you out of your mind? What on earth `snapd` is for IOT!!!! What are you saying??? Go take your next medicine...

Comment: I have 2 ubuntu systems both of them are LAPTOPs!!!! is Laptop an IOT ????????

Comment: Even if snap is for IOT, How can you accept the fact that automatic updates is good for IOT? What if they installed something that could control all the IOT devices on earth... I don't know if you believe in conspiracy but if you read history, there were many things that have happened that have been completey planned from the start... You wanna let them control your SMART home just by a click of a button? An insane person does that...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do it for sure.
The repository is at the address: https://github.com/snapcore/snapd

The code is open source you can edit it yourself. I think in the near future as the debate around `snapd` automatic updates heats up (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23052108), we could see different versions of snap ...